# div tags within div tags does not appear after appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, css

I'm writing a function to create two cards -one is square and another round in shape to display on a button's click. When another button is pressed, few more styles gets added. 
But the problem I'm running into is that the div squareMainID and roundMainID both of them have same number of divs within divs. When the div gets displayed on the DOM, only roundMainId's div tags and children shows up(see image). If you can see the dev tool, the black arrows next to the roundMainID is collapsable. Not the same for SqaureMainID. Even the styles that I'm trying to apply gets applied only to the roundMainID and not to the square. Why is this happening and how to fix?

[image]

code:

```
var pick= document.getElementById("pick");
var attachCardsDiv = document.createElement("div");
attachCardsDiv.className += "attach-cards-div"
var squareMainDiv = document.createElement("div");
squareMainDiv.className = "cardsPanel";
squareMainDiv.setAttribute("id", "squareMainID"); 
var roundMainDiv = document.createElement("div");
roundMainDiv.className = "cardsPanel"; 
roundMainDiv.setAttribute("id", "roundMainID"); 
var classADiv = document.createElement("div");
var classBDiv = document.createElement("div");
var apple = document.createElement("div");
var banana = document.createElement("div");


function attachTwoCardsOnDom(){
  classBDiv.appendChild(banana);
  classBDiv.appendChild(apple);
  classADiv.appendChild(classBDiv)
  squareMainDiv.appendChild(classADiv).addEventListener('click', 
    function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
  });
  attachCardsDiv.appendChild(squareMainDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(attachCardsDiv);


// ************************************************************


  classBDiv.appendChild(banana);
  classBDiv.appendChild(apple);
  classADiv.appendChild(classBDiv)
  roundMainDiv.appendChild(classADiv).addEventListener('click', 
  function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
  });
  attachCardsDiv.appendChild(roundMainDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(attachCardsDiv);
}



pick.addEventListener('click', function(event){       
  attachTwoCardsOnDom();
})
```

html:

```
<button id="pick">Press</button>
```

Comment: create helper functions to keep code more readable and manageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
var classADiv = document.createElement("div");
var classBDiv = document.createElement("div");
var apple = document.createElement("div");
var banana = document.createElement("div");
```

You create the `div`s just once and then in:

```
function attachTwoCardsOnDom(){
  classBDiv.appendChild(banana);
  classBDiv.appendChild(apple);
  classADiv.appendChild(classBDiv)
```

you just **move them around**.

That is, you actually are adding to `squareMainDiv`, but later you are removing them from it when adding the `div`s to `roundMainDiv`.

**Fix:** You have to recreate the `div`s every time:

```
function attachTwoCardsOnDom(){
  var classADiv = document.createElement("div");     // creating here
  var classBDiv = document.createElement("div");     // creating here
  var apple = document.createElement("div");         // creating here
  var banana = document.createElement("div");        // creating here

  classBDiv.appendChild(banana);
  classBDiv.appendChild(apple);
  classADiv.appendChild(classBDiv)
  squareMainDiv.appendChild(classADiv).addEventListener('click', 
    function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
  });
  attachCardsDiv.appendChild(squareMainDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(attachCardsDiv);


// ************************************************************

  var classADiv2 = document.createElement("div");     // creating here, different name
  var classBDiv2 = document.createElement("div");     // creating here, different name
  var apple2 = document.createElement("div");         // creating here, different name
  var banana2 = document.createElement("div");        // creating here, different name


  classBDiv2.appendChild(banana2);                    // notice classBDiv2 (2!)
  classBDiv2.appendChild(apple2);                     // and on...
  classADiv2.appendChild(classBDiv2)
  roundMainDiv.appendChild(classADiv2).addEventListener('click', 
  function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
  });
  attachCardsDiv.appendChild(roundMainDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(attachCardsDiv);
}
```

Demo JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/s41ax3rb/3/

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-)